# How to store multiple textbox values into one application variable in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, json, html, bootstrapping

`[code page="c#"]
  Hdnano.Value = Application["AccountNum"].ToString();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#ano").on("blur", function() {
        var accountNum = $('textarea#ano').val();
        $("#Hdnano").val(folioNum);
      });
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
          SELECT bank name
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
          father name
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
          father mobile no
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
          mother name
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
          mother mobile no
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
          Account numbers
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="fno"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

How to store multiple textbox values  into one application variable ?
here Customer details which are select bank name ,father/mother name and mobile number into one application variable ,and the multiple account numbers which is in text area into second application variable ?I want to store values of customer into application variable and than want to pass this values onto other page which is also similar kind of this html page.How can I use here json string

Comment: In which language, `C#` or `jQuery`?

Comment: In C# language @Equalsk

Comment: Well it really depends on what you want to do with it afterwards, but I'd consider a `Dictionary<string, string>` a single variable, where the key is the textbox name and the value is the textbox text, e.g. `key = "bank name", value = "HSBC"`.

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can name variables like array elements. Look at this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name1[first]">
    <input type="text" name="name1[second]">
    <input type="text" name="name1[third]">

    <input type="text" name="name2[0]">
    <input type="text" name="name2[1]">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```